# Access To Javascript Console From MeteorJS App On Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, meteor

my concern is related to security. is it possible that someone with my mobile app deployment acess the javascript console.

i know it is possible to deploy to the app with the details shown: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile

when deployed to the device, you can still hit localhost:port on the computers browser and you will see the app... but i want to know if it is possible for someone who downloaded the standalone app from the apple/android app store has the ability to do this.

i know know with ios you can put ios safari into debug mode, connect it to your computer and it will seem to work as debugging on a regular website. however i want to know if this is possible for a stand alone app deployment.

MeteorJS is essentially an "OS web browser" wrapped inside a native app container. what i want to know is if that "OS web browser" can give users the ability to access its javascript console.

sorry for being so verbose, ive run out of things to google in relation to this issue and ^^ those are my finding so far.

please let me know if i am being unclear.

Comment: Could you explain why you think access to the JavaScript console would pose a security threat?

Comment: I have database related functions via meteor methods I don't want the user to have access too. Nothing critical but ideally the user should never have the ability to modify the database without the UI.

Comment: If this is an issue then you're not setting permissions (correctly) http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access javascript console on a standalone app (and has a webview) installed from app store. Usb debugging should be enabled on android device (android 4.4+) and Web inspect should be enabled on iOS safari settings.

You can enable usb debugging and goto `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome browser to debug standalone apps that run webviews and installed on android devices. More info -> https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

You can use Gapdebug to inspect both iOS and Android apps -> https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

As others pointed you should be using meteor's Allow and Deny to restrict users from running certain methods.